# Having trouble with AngularJS url using $location and ngView

Tags: angularjs, url-routing

I'm having multiple issues with AngularJS URLs using $location. The basic url is : `http://localhost:3000/`.

### First

When I click on a `<a>` tag to move the index of the page to an id : `<a href="#home">Home</a>`.
The url becomes : `http://localhost:3000/home` and the page offset doesn't change. I have to click again to get `http://localhost:3000/home#home` so that the offset change.

### Second

So because I'm using `$routeProvider` configuration (see "Application configuration" below), I'm using `ng-view` in my index.html (first page loaded):

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-view class="{{class}}"></div>
</body>
```

The problem here is that I can't change the `ng-view` content. The first view `views/home.html` is correctly loaded though. On the home.html page, I have : `<a href="/register">Registration</a>`.
My base url is still the same, when I first click on this link, the url becomes : `http://localhost:3000/register`. Which looks correct ! But the view doesn't change. I still have `views/home.html` on my page.

### Third

The `.otherwise()` rule on Application configuration doesn't redirect if I type an url like : `http://localhost:3000/toto`, it writes `Cannot GET /toto` on the page.

### Application configuration

```
angular.module("app", ["ngRoute", "ui.bootstrap"])
    .config(["$locationProvider", "$routeProvider", function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "views/home.html",
            controller: "HomeCtrl"
        })
        .when("/:id", {
            templateUrl: "views/home.html",
            controller: "HomeCtrl"
        })
        .when("/register", {
            templateUrl: "views/register.html",
            controller: "RegisterCtrl"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "views/error.html"
        });
    }]);
```

This are multiple problems, I write them all at once, because maybe they are related. But I'm really having a lot of trouble with this features. I'm wondering if I shouldn't use ngInclude instead of ngView.

Can anyone explain me all this wrong behaviors and what I did wrong ?

Also is there a best practice to use ngView ? Or in a specific context ?

Comment: For the first issue you have to set the href to what you have in the $routeProvider config. `#home` should just be `#` since in the config you have it set to '/'

Comment: For the second issue you should have the href set to '#register'

Comment: @Rorschach120 Even if `/register` is a new page ? (new view)

Comment: Third and finally, redirectTo is looking for a url not a template. Create a route for '/error' and set `redirectTo: '/error'`

Comment: Yes that is the correct syntax for loading a route through a href.

Comment: Everything is not working as expected. =/ The first: doing that you're breaking the behavior I was looking for, it doesn't move ah the home id at all now. The second: it brings me to the first problem with `#home` and it doesn't change the page. The third: seems logic but doesn't work. Also, for the third one, I'm wondering if I won't need a server configuration for the `/error` url, so I can't really tell right now.

Comment: try using '/home/:id' instead. All of my answers will work though, you must be setting it up wrong. Especially the third one.

Comment: Check out this tutorial: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07